# Socket io.on many namespaces path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I haven't work with socket io before so I feel a little bit lost right now.

I try to make a chat. I have a system when users send a private message to another it makes a connection between them (Creat chat id).

Now I try to find a solution for how front-end listen for an event from many chat id.
Now the system looks like this I am not sure if this one is a correct solution.

```js
Front-end
io(`/privateMessage/${user._id}`).on('message')
```

```js
Back-end
      io.of(`privateMessage/${toRecipientId}`)
      .emit('message')
```

My question is it is possible that the client can listen from array namespaces like chat Id or I should stick to first solution?

Comment: Can you share a little bit of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use "rooms" approach:

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Rooms

Syntax, how to connect to a few rooms, is the following:

```
socket.join(['room1', 'room2']);
```